# Solver constraints ignored

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I'm trying to run the following:

```vb
Sub getNoShortSalePortfolio()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim assetReturns As ListObject
Set assetReturns = ws.ListObjects("tblAssetReturns")

Dim numColumnsAssets As Long
numColumnsAssets = assetReturns.ListColumns.Count
    
Dim portfolioWeightsVector() As Variant
Dim activeCellAddress As Variant
Dim adjustableCellsAddress As String

activeCellAddress = ws.Range("noShortSale").Address
   
adjustableCellsAdress = activeCellAddress & ":" & Range(activeCellAddress).Offset(numColumnsAssets - 2, 0).Address

Range(adjustableCellsAdress).ClearContents

Solverreset

SolverOptions Precision:=0.0001, Iterations:=10, AssumeNonNeg:=True
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("noShortSaleMean"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress) ', EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

SolverAdd CellRef:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("noShortSaleWeightSum"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("noShortSaleVola"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Range("portfolioVolaAssetShare")

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
End Sub
```

However, my solver iterates just two times and returns a vector of solutions that are all equal (in my case say 10% as I want to constrain the sum of my solutions to be smaller or equal to 100%).

Furthermore, I want another constraint that a function of my solution vector meets a predetermined value from another cell, however, the solver seems to ignore this constraint.

**Screenshot of the solver**
[image]

**Manually running the solver with**
[image]

**reaches the desired (and expected solution):**
[image]

However, it seems the target cell and the other constraint are not defined in my VBA.

Comment: Does the solver report that it found a valid solution or not?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the manual configuration of solver?

Comment: Did not ask what the solution was . Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Sub getNoShortSalePortfolio()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim assetReturns As ListObject
Set assetReturns = ws.ListObjects("tblAssetReturns")

Dim numColumnsAssets As Long
numColumnsAssets = assetReturns.ListColumns.Count
    
Dim portfolioWeightsVector() As Variant
Dim activeCellAddress As Variant
Dim adjustableCellsAddress As String

activeCellAddress = ws.Range("noShortSale").Address

adjustableCellsAdress = activeCellAddress & ":" & Range(activeCellAddress).Offset(numColumnsAssets - 2, 0).Address

Range(adjustableCellsAdress).ClearContents

Solverreset

SolverOptions Precision:=0.000001, Iterations:=20, AssumeNonNeg:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="noShortSaleMean", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
'SolverOk SetCell:="noShortSaleVola", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

SolverAdd CellRef:=Range(adjustableCellsAdress), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:="noShortSaleWeightSum", Relation:=2, FormulaText:=1
SolverAdd CellRef:="noShortSaleVola", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="portfolioVolaAssetShare"

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1 
End Sub
```

I found one way to solve this issue.. I need to remove these Range() stuff, then it behaves normally (.i.e. as the manual solution)